# Excel 2013 When conditions are met, I need to copy the whole row to another worksheet. Possible?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a worksheet with a list of employees. We have two companies, (Valley Tool and Valley Farm) so two of the columns (C and E) are for the date of employee termination. Our HR guy would like to have this spreadsheet set up so that when he enters a value in one of those cells, Excel will automatically copy that row to another worksheet incrementally to create a list of terminated employees.  I'm not an expert on Excel but I've read a lot about conditional formatting and haven't found that this is even possible. If it isn't, it seems like it would be a helpful thing to be able to do.  Is it possible to do this?

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it's possible with a macro (or possibly an array formula). Look in to [`Worksheet_Change()` events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx).

Comment: It is certainly possible, though I haven't had the time to look into exactly how. But you mention **conditional formatting**, which is certainly **not** what you are looking for. Conditional formatting will apply a formatting (color, cell color, font, etc.) to this row if condition met, it will not copy anything to somewhere else.

Comment: @BruceWayne is right. You are looking for some event that triggers some action : fill a cell --> copy the row somewhere else. The only way to handle this is using VBA and the Worksheet_Change() events. You mention conditional formatting but you may not need it. Indeed, your VBA code will wait for some input in the desire columns, checks that correct values have been filled and then process the row. You will not need cond formatting anymore has row will be somewhere else. If you are interested in some code example to handle this, I can provide but be sure you can actually use .XLSM files.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it sounds like your best option would be to write a macro.

However, if you want to use cell formulas, here is something you could try.
Copy this to the first cell of your second sheet, and drag it to the other cells:

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!$A1)),NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!A1))),Sheet1!A1,"")
```

This checks that cell A1 from Sheet1 is not blank (Note the $A1 ensures it is always checking the first column, regardless of where you drag the formula)

The second part of the AND is checking that A1 is not blank (this value will change as you populate the formula to your second sheet).  For example, if you drag this formula to G1 on your second sheet, it will make sure that the matching G1 from sheet1 is not blank.  That way, it does not try to copy any extraneous cells and evaluate them as "0"

If your desired condition is met (in this example, having a non-blank value in the "A" column), the formula will evaluate to the same cell value as on the other sheet.

NOTE:  this is assuming both sheets will have the exact same layout.  You may need to tweak it, if perhaps there is additional data, or headings.  For example, you might want to read the value from 4 rows above your current row, instead of exactly replacing cell A5 on sheet2 with A5 on sheet1.